# IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated

Tags: session, jsf, jboss, icefaces, illegalstateexception

I have a problem with my first JSF/IceFaces (version 1.8.2) application running on JBoss 5.1.0.

I recieve an exception after a while, telling me about session problems. This is weird, because i do not use sessions in my code at all. The following logs show that none of my backing beans can be instantiated because of this error (from JBoss):

```
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: bean.Abgrenzungsreise.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:141)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.getSelectItems(MenuRenderer.java:637)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.countSelectOptionsRecursive(MenuRenderer.java:448)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:377)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:119)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.renderkit.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:370)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:208)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:358)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.util.CustomComponentUtils.renderChild(CustomComponentUtils.java:339)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSetRenderer.writeTabCell(PanelTabSetRenderer.java:977)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSetRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelTabSetRenderer.java:423)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:503)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:456)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:77)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:52)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:696)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:58)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SessionExpiredException: User session has expired or it was invalidated.
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ProxyHttpSession.getAttribute(ProxyHttpSession.java:77)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletSessionAttributeMap.getAttribute(ServletSessionAttributeMap.java:16)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.AbstractAttributeMap.containsKey(AbstractAttributeMap.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.isBeanInScope(BeanManager.java:177)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:82)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at bean.Abgrenzungsreise.(Abgrenzungsreise.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 86 more 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:110)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ProxyHttpSession.getAttribute(ProxyHttpSession.java:75)
    ... 100 more
2011-01-28 08:05:54,326 ERROR [com.icesoft.faces.context.View] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-3) Problem encountered during View.servePage 
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: bean.Abgrenzungsreise.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:368)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:86)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:61)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:107)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:141)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.getSelectItems(MenuRenderer.java:637)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.countSelectOptionsRecursive(MenuRenderer.java:448)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:377)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:119)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.renderkit.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:370)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:208)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.DomBasicRenderer.encodeParentAndChildren(DomBasicRenderer.java:358)
    at com.icesoft.faces.renderkit.dom_html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:96)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:837)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.util.CustomComponentUtils.renderChild(CustomComponentUtils.java:339)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSetRenderer.writeTabCell(PanelTabSetRenderer.java:977)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.paneltabset.PanelTabSetRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelTabSetRenderer.java:423)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:861)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:503)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:497)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderResponse(D2DViewHandler.java:456)
    at com.icesoft.faces.application.D2DViewHandler.renderView(D2DViewHandler.java:159)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.JsfLifecycleExecutor.apply(JsfLifecycleExecutor.java:19)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2$1.respond(View.java:48)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletRequestResponse.respondWith(ServletRequestResponse.java:201)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View$2.serve(View.java:77)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.View.servePage(View.java:149)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SingleViewServer.service(SingleViewServer.java:52)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.ServerProxy.service(ServerProxy.java:11)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainSessionBoundServlet$4.service(MainSessionBoundServlet.java:149)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.common.standard.PathDispatcherServer.service(PathDispatcherServer.java:24)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.BasicAdaptingServlet.service(BasicAdaptingServlet.java:16)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.SessionDispatcher.service(SessionDispatcher.java:53)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.PathDispatcher.service(PathDispatcher.java:23)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:131)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:310)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:696)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:58)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.core.SessionExpiredException: User session has expired or it was invalidated.
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ProxyHttpSession.getAttribute(ProxyHttpSession.java:77)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ServletSessionAttributeMap.getAttribute(ServletSessionAttributeMap.java:16)
    at com.icesoft.faces.context.AbstractAttributeMap.containsKey(AbstractAttributeMap.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.isBeanInScope(BeanManager.java:177)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:82)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at bean.Abgrenzungsreise.(Abgrenzungsreise.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getAttribute: Session already invalidated
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.getAttribute(StandardSession.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.getAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:110)
    at com.icesoft.faces.webapp.http.servlet.ProxyHttpSession.getAttribute(ProxyHttpSession.java:75)
    ... 100 more
```

I recognized that the exception is thrown an half hour after the last user activity.

Comment: I recognized that the error occurs 30 minutes after the last user action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem has been reported on the IceFaces forums:

- http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/7752.page
- http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/18154.page

The proposed solutions were:

> This was happening for us once we set the asynchronous mode off
>
> ```
> <!-- Specifies to the ICEfaces framework that synchronous update mode is to be
> used. By default, ICEfaces uses asynchronous update mode to support
> server-initiated updates (AJAX push). Setting to true will enable
> synchronous update mode and disable AJAX push features. -->
> <context-param>
>     <param-name>com.icesoft.faces.synchronousUpdate</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
> </context-param>
> ```
>
> When this was false we got the nice little session timed out message.
>   When this was true, session timeout behaviour was stack trace.

and

> In the meantime I've switched from ICEfaces 1.8.2 to what's in the svn repository at the moment (1.8.3+). And the behavior has changed. There is no crash anymore.

As to your statement that you aren't using the session anywhere, the stacktrace tells that it is attempting to create a session scoped managed bean when this exception was thrown. So you are definitely using the session :)

---

**Update** as per the comments: You should indeed definitely not assign the (request based!!) `FacesContext` as a `static` variable. Also, injecting of other beans needs to be taken place by `<managed-property>` in `faces-config.xml`. Otherwise it isn't "injecting" at all, but just *manually* accessing the other bean. With injecting, you're letting JSF do the work to set the other bean as a property of the current bean. An example can be found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther).

Comment: @BalusC: The OP did probably not intend to use sessions, but i assume that he uses something that requires them under the hood.

Comment: @elusive: the stacktrace tells that he has a `<f:selectItems>` which is bound to a session scoped managed bean. It's definitely declared in the view by himself. Probably he wasn't aware of the meaning of the "session scope" and he actually meant that he isn't calling `request.getSession()` or whatever manually in his own code.

Comment: First, thank you for your answer. This was configured like your suggestion by default. So this don't seems to be the reason for the error.

Comment: So it is already `false`? And upgrading to 1.8.3 or newer didn't help?

Comment: I was aware about the fact that there are some session things behind the scence. what i wanted to say in my question was that i did't use them explicitly. Could this error be caused by injecting one session bean into another by `private static FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); private utils.Error errorBean;` and in the constructor of the bean `errorBean = (utils.Error) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "error");`?

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, it was set false by default.

Comment: I couldn't use the latest version of icefaces, as BalusC wrote, beacause our jboss runs with version 1.8.2 and my application is not the only one running on it. Also my app is not important enougth to setup a new one for it.

Comment: The time from last user action to the exception is configured with `<session-config>
      <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> 
    </session-config>`
the parameter is the time in minutes.

Comment: OK, thank you for your advice to bean-injection. I am sure this will help very much for the current and future projects with jsf.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the exception was in my SessionBean classes.
I asked above if the reason can be the injection of beans into another via the facesContext.
Now i give the answer my self: "Yes it can be the reason."

```
public class MySessionBean {
    private static FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    private utils.AnotherSessionBean injectedSessionBean = (utils.AnotherSessionBean) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "anotherSessionBean");
    // ...
}
```

I felt free to instantiate the current FacesContext outside of any method or the constructor, which was not a good idea, because after the session-timeout i used the old one or mabey no session context. MySessionBean was reloaded or get a new instance of it, but it didn't refresh the FacesContext. The result of this is described above^^

Conclusion: So getting the FacesContext belongs in the codeblock of a method or       constructor.

Thank you very much for your help!