# Spring boot async: get HttpServletRequest inside async method

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've enabled async into my spring boot application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class BackOfficeConfiguration {}
```

and I've created this async method:

```
@Async
public void importDocuments() {}
```

`importDocuments` code is just:

```
@Async
public void importDocuments() {
    // Do something

    // Get current request context
    ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = 
        (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
    HttpServletRequest request = requestAttributes.getRequest();
}
```

On `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()`, spring boot is getting me this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

How could I get current `HttpServletRequest` inside an async method?

Comment: Don't. Pas the needed objects/data into the method, or use proper async for your web layer.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using @Async on a method, that means that method throws into another new thread(separated one). that means, it is not related to your current request. (those are two roads).  if you want to get some data from the request, you have to get the data that you want from the request and keep it as a copy. Because, after complete the request data will be removed. if you had passed the reference there, you will get an error when accessing the data like `No thread-bound request found`. you have to create a `Cloneable` object and fill the data into that object and get a clone before calling the Async method and call the Async method by passing that object. then you have a copy of that data and you can use it inside pf your new thread (@Async method). A Cloneable class like below.

```java
public class CloneableClass implements Cloneable {
    //
    private ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes;
    //getters
    //setters

    @Override
    public CloneableClass  clone() {
        try {
            CloneableClass clone = (CloneableClass) super.clone();
            return clone;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

}
```

read more on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33337838/418599 .

**AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor.java**

```java
public class AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {

    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "AsyncPoolExecutor";

    private static class ContextAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
        private Callable<T>       task;
        private RequestAttributes context;

        public ContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task, RequestAttributes context) {
            this.context = context;
            this.task    = task;
        }

        @Override
        public T call() throws Exception {
            if (null != context) {
                RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(context);
            }

            try {
                return task.call();
            } finally {
                RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
            }
        }
    }

    private <T> ContextAwareCallable getContextAwareCallable(Callable<T> task) {
        return new ContextAwareCallable(
            task,
            RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submit(
            getContextAwareCallable(task)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public <T> CompletableFuture<T> submitCompletable(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submitCompletable(
            getContextAwareCallable(task)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public <T> ListenableFuture<T> submitListenable(Callable<T> task) {
        return super.submitListenable(
            getContextAwareCallable(task)
        );
    }

}
```

**AsyncExceptionHandler.java**

```java
@Slf4j
public final class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... params) {
        log.error(
            throwable.getMessage(),
            throwable
        );
    }

}
```

**AsyncConfiguration.java**

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public abstract class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncSettings asyncSettings;

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        AsyncSettings.Thread.Prefix   prefix   = asyncSettings.getThread().getPrefix();
        AsyncSettings.Pool.Size       size     = asyncSettings.getPool().getSize();

        AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor executor = new AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor();

        executor.setBeanName(AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor.BEAN_NAME);
        executor.setCorePoolSize(size.getCore());
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(size.getMax());
        executor.setQueueCapacity(asyncSettings.getQueue().getCapacity());
        executor.setThreadGroupName(prefix.getGroup());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(prefix.getThread());

        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }

    @Bean(AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor.BEAN_NAME)
    public Executor getAsyncExecutorBean() {
        return getAsyncExecutor();
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new AsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

}
```

**SpringBoot Controller**

```java
@Autowired
private DefaultApiLogic defaultApiLogic;
    
@Async(AsyncContextAwarePoolExecutor.BEAN_NAME)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Version>> getVersion() {

    String            requestBaseUrl;
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();

    if (requestAttributes != null) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getRequest();
        requestBaseUrl             = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    } else {
        // Lambda effective initializer
        requestBaseUrl = null;
    }

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        () -> ResponseEntity.ok(
            defaultApiLogic.getVersion(requestBaseUrl)
        ),
        Runnable::run
    );
}
```